# Jenkins Or condition in when block

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to implement an `or` condition for the execution of a stage.
The behaviour I seek is that if the `PROJECT_TAG` parameters is either `project1`, or `project2`, do not execute the stage.

I've tried the following, but it does not seem to work, and executes the stage regardless:

```
  stages {
    stage('Cloudformation Init') {
      when {
        expression {params.PROJECT_TAG != 'project1' || params.PROJECT_TAG != 'project2'}
      }
```

If I just define one parameter in the when block, like the following, it works, and bypasses that particular stage if the `params.PROJECT_TAG` == `project1`. For example, this works:

```
  stages {
    stage('Cloudformation Init') {
      when {
        expression {params.PROJECT_TAG != 'project1'}
      }
```

However, I really need the pipeline to be more flexible, and therefore needed to implment an `or` condition into the when block.
Is this possible?

Comment: your logic is wrong I believe.  If you want to prohibit both `'project1'` and `'project2'` you need to do `params.PROJECT_TAG != 'project1' && params.PROJECT_TAG != 'project2'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 when {
     anyOf {
         expression {params.PROJECT_TAG != 'project1'}; expression {params.PROJECT_TAG != 'project2'}
     }
 }
```